# User-based row order in a SQL table

Tags: postgresql, linked-list, sql-order-by

User should be able to change row order in an Excel-like way. Right now rows are ordered by `id`. So I add another column `order`.

**Example**

```
1) Row A
2) Row B
3) Row C
4) Row D
```

Now `Row A` should be after `Row B`.

```
2) Row B
X) Row A
3) Row C
4) Row D
```

I need to calculate the new order. Therefore I need to update all rows! I don't like that.

**Idea**

I could use a decimal interval of `10` instead of `1`.

```
10.00) Row A
20.00) Row B
30.00) Row C
40.00) Row D
```

Then I could calculate the new order like this: `neworder = before + (after - before) / 2`

`Row A` after `Row B`

```
20.00) Row B
25.00) Row A
30.00) Row C
40.00) Row D
```

... and `Row C` after `Row B`

```
20.00) Row B
22.50) Row C
25.00) Row A
40.00) Row D
```

... and `Row D` after `Row C`

```
20.00) Row B
22.50) Row C
23.75) Row D
25.00) Row A
```

Is there a better way to deal with this kind of problem?

**Edit** @Adam suggest a singly linked linear list. It would do the job. But what about ordering and what about performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your 'order' column to a 'previous column' record, then each re-ordering would only need two row edits.  To use your last example:  (I'm giving the first row the token value of 'NULL'.)

Row A after Row B

```
NULL) Row B
B) Row A
A) Row C
C) Row D
```

... and Row C after Row B (Change Row A to C and Row C to B)

```
NULL) Row B
B) Row C
C) Row A
A) Row D
```

... and Row D after Row C (Change Row D to C and Row A to D)

```
NULL) Row B
B) Row C
C) Row D
D) Row A
```

Comment: A singly linked linear list would do the job. But what about ordering and what about performance?

Comment: A basic linked list would give you ordering capability.  The maintainability would be better than what you describe above.  
If you want to maximize performance, there are definitely better algorithms and structures, depending on how much work you want to do; just do some research on list data structures.

Comment: Of course is there an order but I would need to do a recursive select over all rows.